# configurableSwatches not working after update

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, configurable-swatches

I've updated from 1.8 to 1.9.3.10
I've managed to make the update after several problems, but in the end what has worked was:
(I'm working on a dev site to "try" the update procedure)

1) update everything the connect manager highlighted with the last stable version
2) copy all the 1.9.3.10 files from a fresh package on he server (this was done to solve one of the update issues, as a test, and it worked)
3) copied the local.xml and all the theme files into the new updated system.

now, if I:
set app/etc/modules/Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml to "false" I can see the frontend.

if I set it to "true" the frontend goes blank, and in the system.log these lines are logged:

```
2018-11-06T12:44:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-11-06T12:44:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/local:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/community:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/core:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/local/TypoStores/Less/Model')  in /home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

also, if I go in the backend, in the configuration of the configurable swatches, clicking on the link to "configure" them, a 404 page in admin is presented.
I've also tried to switch to the default theme, but the frontend keep being blank.

what can I do? may I "reinstall" that configurableswatches? how?

Comment: Is this file `app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php` there?

Comment: interesting enough, that file was a "directory" called Collection.php, I have found several other directories with this name pattern (the php extension),  so I've copied all the 1.9.3.10 over the old files and now everything is working.